# Get data from FCM without clicking the notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM on My android app and successfully get the notification, then the problem is I want to get the data from FCM payload without clicking the notification, so I can add the data from FCM to my List. Is there a way to get data from FCM without clicking the notification?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all customized data under the **onMessageReceived**

**Example:**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String yourData = data.get("YOUR_DATA_TAG_HERE");
    }
}
```